# Implementing Spring WS Security

Tags: java, web-services, spring-ws, ws-security

I am implementing a Spring WS in NetBeans IDE and JDK1.6. The Spring-WS version is 2.0.4. Though I have implemented the provider by going through the tutorial on Spring site but I am unable to implement the security features. Can anybody explain the overall security framework in WebServices like where are the certificates placed on the server and how the request is validated against them. Also the spring site doesnt contains enough info about the terms like keystores, certificates, trusted stores. Can anybody explain how are these related to Spring WS and how can they be created and used ? I am just getting more and more confused ?

Comment: Today I read some tutorials and created keystores and certificates using java keytool utility. The tutorial is placed at http://www.techbrainwave.com/?p=953. Now I want to know how can I configure my client and server in Spring WS to use these files ? Can anyone guide me through that ?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented Spring WSS few weeks ago and all the information you need can be found in this [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html). There, you can find information about certificates and keystores but you should look for in other place if you need more information about as Spring WSS just uses certificates for signing and validating the messages.

Particulary, for signing a message you need to create a interceptor as it is described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html#d4e2706). Once your interceptor is ready, you can add it to the ingoing messages or to the outgoing

Also, I recommend you to debug your SOAP messages as it is described here to see what is going on with your messages.